# sympy: plot implicit function of erf

Tags: python, sympy

```
x,y = sympy.symbols("x y")
f = sympy.erf(x+y) - 1
sympy.plot_implicit(f)
```

Is it possible to plot this in Sympy 1.9 and NumPy 1.21.4, or an upgrade path for either that allows me to plot this, or a workaround I can use?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please report here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: In the meantime and as a workaround would it be possible to generate the data without plotting? So I can plot manually?

Comment: Are you sure about `erf(x+y) - 1`?  `erf(x+y)` never reaches `1` for finite `x` and `y`.

Comment: 1) No I was typing random values after I couldn't plot my function but that totally makes sense 2) It doesn't matter, i.e. same error with 0.5 3) Is [this staircase](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=erf%28x%2By%29%3D1) a visualization of the error in the approximation of *erf* used by WolframAlpha? 4) Is [erf(x+y)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=erf%28x%2By%29%3D1%2F2) linear? 5) Now I really want an interactive plot of erf. 6) I guess that makes sense, `x+y = erfinv(1/2)` 7) But a sum of erfs isn't necessarily linear

Comment: You should be able to do this with matplotlib's contour function.